# Script that runs all of the scripts but in correct order in typescript

Tags: typescript, import, async-await, build

I currently have 3 scripts that I initiate before the build. `sc1.ts`, `sc2.ts`, `sc2.ts`.

It's important that all 3 scripts wait for each other and not run all together.

I've created `allSc.ts` and did the following:

```
import "./sc1.ts"
import "./sc2.ts"
import "./sc3.ts"
```

Now whenever I initiate `allSc.ts` on build it runs all of them at the same time and causes a lot of issues. Is there a way to make scripts in `AllSc.ts` await for each other?

Update:

I think I'm close, but it still doesn't work:

```
import sc1 from "./sc1";
import sc2 from "./sc2";
import sc3 from "./sc3";

const runScripts = async () => {
  new Promise(function () {
    sc1();
  })
    .then(function () {
      return new Promise(function () {
        sc2();
      });
    })
    .then(function () {
      return new Promise(function () {
        sc3();
      });
    });
};

runScripts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dynamic import? e.g.

```
   import("./sc1")
    .then(sc1 => sc1())
    .then(() => import("./sc2"))
    .then(sc2 => sc2())
    .then(() => import("./sc3"))
    .then(sc3 => sc3());
```

Update: the above assumes each function is async, e.g.

```
async function sc1(): Promise<void> {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(); // or reject
}
```

Comment: Runs all of them at the same time as well

Comment: They don't run at the same time. They are kicked off at different time, Depend on how sc1,2,3 actually runs, i.e. how does sc2 knows sc1 finishes running, since sc1 might be sync. so in order to achieve async, you can make sc1 return a promise

Comment: Each script has a function that runs the whole script, so I assume I should make that function a promise and wait until it's done?

Comment: yes, that should work...